# How to get Selected Listbox Items using devexpress in winforms app?

Tags: winforms, listbox, devexpress, listboxitem

I am trying to get selected item text. I used this below code

```
MessageBox.Show(listBoxColumnHeaders.SelectedItems);
```

**Output**

`Devexpress.XtraEditors.BaseListboxControl+SelectedItemCollection`

But my text is **Country**

**Update**

I add listbox items from another class. That class called `FilterColumnHeader` using below code

```
FilterControl fc = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FilterControl>().SingleOrDefault();
List<FilterColumnHeader> headers = new List<FilterColumnHeader>();
while (rd.Read())
{                                                
    headers.Add(new FilterColumnHeader { typeOfHeader = rd["type"].ToString(), columnHeadersName = rd["AsHeading"].ToString() });

}
fc.listBoxColumnHeaders.DisplayMember = "columnHeadersName";
fc.listBoxColumnHeaders.ValueMember = "typeOfHeader";
fc.listBoxColumnHeaders.DataSource = headers;
```

Now When I try to print using this below code,

```
 MessageBox.Show(""+ listBoxColumnHeaders.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
```

It is showing in message box like below

```
`ProjectName.FilterColumnHeader`
```

Comment: SelectedItems is a collection of Items. You want to display a single item so you need to use an indexer. Try with SelectedItems[0].ToString();

Comment: @Steve Now it is printing class name from where I add the listbox items.

Comment: @Steve can you check my update

Comment: Sorry but I am not an expert of DevExpress controls. However It seems that your headers are a list of FilterColumnHeader. This class has a property called columnHeadersName. This is probably the property to retrieve from your _var fch = SelectedItems[0] as FilterColumnHeader;_ and then use the property _fch.columnHeadersName._

Answer (score 0):

The **SelectedItems** property returns a collection of selected objects. All you need to do is to cast the required object to your type:

```
var filterColumnHeader = (FilterColumnHeader)listBoxControl.SelectedItems[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found an answer but this works for me :

```
StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in listBoxColumnHeaders.SelectedItems)
    {
      list.AppendLine(item as string);
    }
MessageBox.Show(list.ToString());
```